# Homomorphism between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

[image: From Wikipedia]

Don't the first two conditions imply the third one?

Comment: No. Inverse of a continuous function is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Please type out your image - not all users can see images and they are also not searchable so less people will see your question

Answer (score 3):

No. If $X$ is the real line with discrete topology and $Y$ is the same set with the usual topology then the identity map satisfies the first two properties but its inverse map is not continuous.